# Computer does not recognize network drive name

Tags: network-shares, path, network-drive

My desktop is connected to a network drive whose IP address is `\\10.7.50.3`.
The same drive can also be reached simply by going to `\\fea-fe1` and if I `ping fea-fe1`, here is the result:

```
Pinging fea-fe1 [10.7.50.3] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.7.50.3: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.7.50.3: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.7.50.3: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.7.50.3: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=127
```

So it's all working as intended.

My problem is when I try to do the same thing on my laptop, it doesn't work.
My laptop can access the network drive using `\\10.7.50.3` but not `\\fea-fe1`, and when I try to `ping fea-fe1` it returns `Ping request could not find host fea-fe1. Please check the name and try again.`

Why isn't my laptop recognizing that `\\fea-fe1` is equivalent to `\\10.7.50.3`?

It causes a lot of problems as I need to access the  files on that drive using a `\\fea-fe1` path.

Comment: look for fea-fe1 in your desktop C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

Comment: @DourHighArch in my hosts file the only thing showing is`# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.`           
`# 127.0.0.1       localhost`               
`# ::1             localhost`

Comment: Could you start by figuring out how the name is currently recognized on the _working_ machine? E.g. install Wireshark, start a capture on the main network interface, ping the server (perhaps after rebooting the client to make sure it isn't cached), then check whether Wireshark has captured DNS responses for that name, or LLMNR responses, or NBNS responses, or mDNS responses...